# How to train samples in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on my final year project on ocr in opencv,i have done segmentation of the image and feature extraction,now i have to train to make it recognize the alphabet ,give me an idea of how to do that

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you have done until now and what feature set you are using. Anyway below links will be a good start.

1) [Basic OCR in OpenCV](http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/) - It uses k-Nearest Neighbours

2) Also try this : [Simple Digit Recognition OCR in OpenCV-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python)

3) OpenCV samples come with an letter-recongnition sample. Have a look at that!!

Finally, work yourself a lot on your project. Google for your doubts. If you don't find any way,
 come here, tell what you have done, and now what is stopping you.