# Need the steps for making an ocr using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr

I am trying to make an OCR library using Haar classifier of opencv.But its not working well.So can you tell me what are the steps for making an OCR? and will it be possible by using Haar classifier?

Comment: This is not how Stackoverflow works... sry!!!

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of books, tutorials etc available on googling.

But there are two books which would be useful for you.

1) [Handbook of Character Recognition and Document Image Analysis by H. Bunke and P. S. P. Wang](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/981022270X)

2) [Optical Character Recognition: An Illustrated Guide to the Frontier (The Springer International Series in Engineering and Computer Science) by Stephen V. Rice, George Nagy and Thomas A. Nartker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/079238492X)

They have got some good deep theory in it.

And you can see a simple digit OCR using kNN in C++ here: [Basic OCR in OpenCV](http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/)

And you can see a simple Python implementation of OCR using kNN in this SOF: [Simple Digit Recognition OCR in OpenCV-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python/9620295#9620295)

In the OpenCV svn, you can see a new Python sample for hand-written recognition using ANN : ...svn\opencv\samples\python2\digits.py . The code is in Python, but all OpenCV functions would be available in C++ too.

Hope this would be sufficient for a start up.