# Extracting Hebrew text from image in python

Tags: python, computer-vision, ocr, hebrew, python-tesseract

I want to extract Hebrew text from an image.

I've tried using pytesseract, but it gets some letters confused (for example ' instead of י or נ instead of כ)

I tried doing some manipulations on the image (such as resizing, removing noise and binarization) which helped a little but still got many mistakes.

I've spent hours searching for better text extraction tools but couldn't find.

So here's my question:

A) Is there a tool I can use that I might have missed?

B) If not, what are the steps to creating my own?

Thanks in advance,
Amichai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choosing the right OCR can be a hard thing, but you seem to be on the right track already (as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489824/how-do-i-choose-between-tesseract-and-opencv) Stackoverflow post).

Generally, if you are not satisfied with the quality of Tesseract, you seem to be (mostly) out of luck; from what I read, it seems that there might be an alternative in
[OCROpus](https://github.com/tmbdev/ocropy), although that seems less straightforward than the PyTesseract approach. 
Also, diving a little deeper into the [GitHub repository of Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) revealed that there is a LSTM-based version 4.0 under active development, which *might* bring you better results. I am not fully aware of what Tesseract version PyTesseract is calling, but it might be worth investigating, since it could be easier to replace Tesseract than think yourself into a fully new environment.

PS: As for the question "how to build my own OCR", I would advise heavily against it. Just collecting all the data and getting the basics right will cost you a lot of effort, and is generally not worth your time; if you get something useful at all, it will likely still be worse than any of the provided libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [HebHTR](https://github.com/Lotemn102/HebHTR)?
It is based on tf1 which is a challenge to integrate.

About `tesseract`, check out this [tutorial](https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/08/03/tesseract-ocr-for-non-english-languages/)