# Python, OpenCV and Sudokus

Tags: opencv, python-3.x, sudoku

With the PDF below, I would like to do the following things.

1. Localize the four sudoku grids so as to treat each of them separately.
2. For each grid picture, I would like to obtain a matrix of the pictures corresponding to each cell.
3. Finally, I would like to "find" the values printed in each cell.

The problem is that I'm a real beginner with OpenCV (I've bought a book about OpenCV with Python but I've not received it yet).

I'm not a beginner in Python, neither in math so every clue is welcomed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck:

[sudoku solver part 1](http://opencvpython.blogspot.hu/2012/06/sudoku-solver-part-1.html)

[part 2](http://opencvpython.blogspot.hu/2012/06/sudoku-solver-part-2.html)

[part 3](http://opencvpython.blogspot.hu/2012/06/sudoku-solver-part-3.html)

[part 4](http://opencvpython.blogspot.hu/2012/07/sudoku-extra.html)

Python 3.x isn't supported by OpenCV though.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've already done my solver. There is still one question. How to localize each grid independently ?

Comment: I believe that part 2 covers that too. He does this for one grid, but you should have no problem doing that for all four.

Comment: I will play with all of this as soon as possible.

Comment: Just to keep this answer up to date, now OpenCV supports Python 3 with OpenCV 3 Beta.

Answer (score 0):

tesseract has nice python bindings, too (and is more specialized on that 'ocr' job ;)

welcome to opencv, though !

Comment: well, it can do letters, it can do digits, too

Comment: Even if it is not summer time, it is christmas time !

Comment: @projetmbc : manually prepare digit OCR in opencv : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python/9620295#9620295

Comment: I will play with that too.