# Recognition of numbers in images(Matlab)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, image-recognition, matlab-cvst

I am learning image processing and i am trying to start my first project, that is Simple number recognition in an image.

So far i have applied thresholding to the image. Now i would like to know some algorithms by which my system can recognize the number in the image. Preferably the algorithm must be simple and it doesn't have to robust as i am would be generating the image in paint using the same font.

I have looked at the similar questions here on SO and they all point out to using libraries. Remember guys i am trying to learn so please don't point out some libraries.

Comment: Try this link, it is OpenCV-Python implementation of OCR using kNN algorithm. I am sure all functions in OpenCV is available in matlab also, just you have find which are they : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python

Comment: @AbidRahmanK thanks for pointing to the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are the numbers printed or hand-written?

The Computer Vision System Toolbox includes a function called `ocr`, which will recognize both, letters and numbers.

If you are looking for hand-written digit recognition, please take a look at this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/digit-classification-using-hog-features.html).