# Capture a Image from a live video streaming and display the image in a static text box using python

Tags: python-2.7, pythoncard, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I am using a parking camera where i need to capture a image of a Number plate from a live video streaming.

I developed a python GUI and i need to capture and display the image, text of the Number plate
as well in the same GUI.

Could any one help me out in developing a python based basic functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV could be helpful for this kind of task. This post covers a similar task and could give you some inspiration on how to tackle the problem (but in C++):     [How to extracting line of text from image using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128253/how-to-extracting-line-of-text-from-image-using-opencv)

Another lengthy post can be found here (all python):
[Simple Digit Recognition OCR in OpenCV-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Check out OpenALPR (http://www.openalpr.com).  This should solve the problem of showing the number plate and the text within it.  It's written in C++ though, so you'd need to hook that into your Python program.