# C# algorithm to detect discrete letters

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing

i am supposed to write a program to detect Arabic alphabetic letters from a noisy environment.i have wrote an algorithm which can detect this type of letters in low noise.but when the noise get increased, detecting letters like `"الف"` in which `"ا"` is apart from `"لف"` going to be a difficult task.is there any algorithm that you can warn me about to work with?i appreciate any advice.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which is a .Net port of the popular OpenCV library for image processing.

What you are trying to do is called [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition), optical character recognition. Two good resources for you:

- A relevant SO post with a very, very detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620295/938695) (code is in Python with OpenCV however) for recognizing numbers:
- Google Scholar [search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=ocr%20arabic&btnG=&as_sdt=1,43&as_sdtp=), OCR is a popular subject and it appears people have been researching the recognition of Arabic.

Comment: thanks for links.i have done something like what mentioned in `Answer`,but the truth is that the environment is not black and white.it has some noises in it.i can get rid of theme by filtering colors,but some of theme is very close to color of letters thus i can't get rid of them.

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili No one can help you unless we know what you have tried, what your data is like, what your code is doing, and what the results are.