# Number recognition in images

Tags: image-processing, image-recognition

I'm very new to programming and what I'm looking for is just a nudge in the right direction as to where I could find the information I need regarding . Who would I need to talk to if I wanted to develop a technology that could recognize numbers and letters in an image?

I know this technology is already out there, so if it's possible, how could I access it for use in another program?

Any tips in terms of what type of professional I need to talk to, sources of information online etc would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you may need to learn about [machine learning module](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/ml.html) (classification techniques) of [opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html).

check similar [questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python) for examples.

[another one](http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/)

also check out [tesseract ocr](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) library, which is an accomplished one.