# How to implement Digit Recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, image-recognition, digits

I want to implement Digit Recognition for my Minor Project. But I've no idea where to start with the topic and also I don't know anything about various ways by which it can be done. Can someone provide various sources and links from where I can studying Digit Recognition first and then build up my knowledge to implement it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple Digit Recognition OCR in OpenCV-Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python)

Answer (score 1):

You need machine learning to solve this problem.

Start with learning basics of machine learning...

Andrew Ng Course on machine learning on coursera is best in my humble opinion to start with.

If you already have some idea about Machine learning and different algorhtms, then  there is a competition in Kaggle about digit recognition, look at the forums where many solutions are shared.

https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/forums

There are a bunch of tools can be used like weka, Vowpal Wabbit, Scikit Learn (python) to solve this problem.

To start with look at the below links
Data Set (Already trained data): http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/
scikit-learn python code:
http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/auto_examples/plot_digits_classification.html

vowpal wabbit have a demo here : https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Examples

Weak example, in Kaggle competitions for digit recognition (But I didn't try them yet)

https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/forums/t/7514/99-46-with-convolutional-nn-weka
https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/forums/t/7221/98-83-with-weka-new-nn-package

Hope this helps.