# Image recognition difficulties with OCR - reading numbers from a picture

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract, image-thresholding

I am trying to develop a python script which can read numbers from pictures, to be more exact I am trying to get the gas consumption. The numbers' locations are always the same. There are two "types" of pics, bright and dark. (I am taking photos every 10 mins so I have a lot of examples if needed)

[image: dark]

[image: bright]

I would like to get as a result 8 digits. e.g. 10974748   (from the dark pic)

I am mainly using Pytesseract and OpenCV2.

So far the best solution seemes to be that first I crop the needed part of the picture than I use `pytesseract.image_to_string()` with config = `--psm 7`. But unfortunately it is really not a reliable solution, it can not recognize the same digit combinations when there were no consumption but photos were taken.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract"
directory = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_pcs\test"

for image in os.listdir(directory):
    
    OriginalImagePath = os.path.join(directory, image)
    OriginalImage = cv2.imread(OriginalImagePath)
    x_start, y_start = int(1110), int(445)
    x_end, y_end = int(1690), int(520)
    cropped_image = OriginalImage[y_start:y_end, x_start:x_end]
    text = (pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_image, config="--psm 7 outputbase digits"))
    cv2.imshow("Cropped", cropped_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    print(text + "    " + OriginalImagePath)
    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After that I tried using thresholding, but sadly I get worse results than with the simple image_to_string. Adaptive thresholding gives an output image which seems not that bad but tesseract can't read it.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract"

img = cv.imread(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test_pcs\new2\2022-10-30_14-49-30.jpg",0)
img = cv.medianBlur(img,5)
ret,th1 = cv.threshold(img,127,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
#'Adaptive Mean Thresholding'
th2 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
#'Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding'
th3 = cv.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

images = [img, th2, th3]
for i in range(3):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')

plt.show()

x_start, y_start = int(1110), int(450)
x_end, y_end = int(1690), int(520)
cropped_image = th2[y_start:y_end, x_start:x_end]

plt.imshow(cropped_image,'gray')

text = (pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_image, config="--psm 7 outputbase digits"))

print("digits: " + text)
```

I also tried to read the digits character by character but it failed as well.

Now I am trying to get better pictures somehow but the options are quite limited.

I would be greateful for any suggestions as I am doing this for my thesis.

Comment: The pictures must be taken from a closer distance.

Comment: Why are the options to get better images limited?

Comment: @YvesDaoust 
I have tried it but the camera can't focus, thus the numbers will be more shady. But thanks for the advice, I will keep trying

Comment: @Markus Because I am using an IP Camera (Imou bullet 2E) and as I have experienced these are the best pictures that it is capable of. But if you have any suggestions how could I improve the image quaility I am happy to try it.

Comment: Did you check this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32756570/18667225 ?