# To detect digits from an image using cv2 and python

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing

I am trying to detect digits located inside a grid and to tell their positions in an image and don't know where to start. So any help is welcome. So far I have used GT Text software but it didn't solve the purpose. Any helper function, libraries, tutorials, links or anything is welcome.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python ?

Comment: Can digits be detected without the training set ? Because in the question which I have to solve conditions allow only one image to be input and that too the experimental one.

Comment: I don't know. I would try to ask people who work with OpenCV: irc.freenode.net at #opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the pytesseract module:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract/0.1

It has a one-liner for what you're trying to do:

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as tes

results = tes.image_to_string(Image.open('test.png'),boxes=True)
```

This will give you `results`, which has each digit and the image coordinates of its bounding box.

You will need to install PIL (python image library, `pip install PIL`) and the tesseract c library (`brew install tesseract` if you have homebrew..) so it's not super trivial but once you have it working, this is the most straight forward OCR in python, and requires no training whatsoever.