# Making my Own training set by distorting text (ANPR System)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

I'm working on an anpr system and to convert the registration plate image to text output. I previously tried to use (py)tessaract to do the ocr for me but this wasn't giving me sufficient results.

As my current training set i'm using this font as all registration fonts are the same

[image: UK number plate font]

from my images some of the resultant number plates will be at weird angles so the plate isn't recognised correctly

So I am asking is there a way to make each digit distorted in many different ways and storing that distortion in an nparray in a file  and from this can perform machine learning techniques on
Something like this (however output to be different)
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Letter+Recognition

Thanks i used a previous point to help me so far to separate characters and so on 
[Recognize the characters of license plate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407608/recognize-the-characters-of-license-plate)

Thanks any help would be appreciated

Comment: There is no problem distorting a text. Use an *homographic* transform. (And I don't think it is necessary to store in a file before training.) Another approach is to figure out the distortion, undistort the text and perform ordinary OCR.