# pytesseract using tesseract 4.0 numbers only not working

Tags: python, tesseract

Any one tried to get numbers only calling the latest version of tesseract 4.0 in python?

The below worked in 3.05 but still returns characters in 4.0, I tried removing all config files but the digits file and still didn't work; any help would be great:

im is an image of a date, black text white background:

```
import pytesseract
im =  imageOfDate
im = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config='outputbase digits')
print(im)
```

Comment: Add image to the question for answerers to see your problem.

Comment: I went with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python/9620295#9620295 instead.

Comment: @CuriousGeorge: Did you find a solution to your upgrade problem?

Comment: Upgrading to v4.1.1 did not help me properly. I also had to download the `tessdata_fast` version of the `trainddata` files. I am attaching a detailed [shell script](https://gist.github.com/ariG23498/b3e46c6e4eaf4da8301e4cae3138987c) to install 4.1.1 from the source.

Answer (score 16):

You can specify the numbers in the `tessedit_char_whitelist` as below as a `config option`.

```
ocr_result = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng', boxes=False, \
           config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

Hope this help.

Comment: "oem" in config argument is mistyped as "eom"

Comment: This solution doesn't work for tesseract 4.0+. There's an open issue related to this on GitHub: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751.

Comment: Tried to fix the typo on May but somehow still showed `--eom`. Anyway, re-fixed it.

Comment: As Jakub mentioned it won't work with 4.0. Instead there is a separate tessdata file for digits

Comment: I'm looking for OCR for recognizing time. E.g. **11:25** . Adding a colon (:) to the whitelist didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Using tessedit_char_whitelist flags with pytesseract did not work for me.  However, one workaround is to use a flag that works, which is config='digits':

```
import pytesseract
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(pixels, config='digits')
```

where pixels is a numpy array of your image (PIL image should also work).  This should force your pytesseract into returning only digits.  Now, to customize what it returns, find your digits configuration file, on Windows mine was located here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata\configs

Open the digits file and add whatever characters you want.  After saving and running pytesseract, it should return only those customized characters.

Comment: what if I need text and digits ?

Comment: you can put both text and digits in the digits config file.  For example, you could put '1234567890abcdefg...' and it will only return those alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Which version are you using ?? the method " config='digits' " doesen't wor for me im usin pytesseract==0.3.0

Comment: Works with the latest tesseract as of 2020

Comment: `config=digits` only do the whitelisting for numeric from alphanumeric input. How to treat an image as only numeric instead of alphanumeric, any ideas? Like treat `l` as `one` instead of `L`

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the numbers in the `tessedit_char_whitelist` as below as a config option.

```
ocr_result = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng',config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751), the blacklist and whitelist doesn't work with tesseract version 4.0.

There are 3 possible solutions for this problem, as I described in [this blog article](https://return2.net/python-tesseract-4-0-get-numbers-only/):

1. Update tesseract to version > 4.1
2. Use the legacy mode as described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46589648/2056125) from [@thewaywewere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4907913/thewaywewere)
3. Create a python function which uses a simple regex to extract all numbers:

   ```
   def replace_chars(text):
       list_of_numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', text)
       result_number = ''.join(list_of_numbers)
       return result_number

   result_number = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Updating to version 4.1.1 from source has solved the problem. https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/releases

Comment: Bad solution  - This is to filter out Text after being detected , totally wrong way.