# How to improve handwritten text recognition using pytesseract in small image?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I want to do handwritten text recognition using the `pytesseract` library to read a numerical character in images that has an average dimension of 43 * 45 pixels. The following sample image:
[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]

**expected result:**

```
9
1
4
```

I want to get a single numerical character from the image.

**I've tried this code below**

```py
import pytesseract

# loop through images
print(pytesseract.image_to_string("text.jpg", config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'))
```

but the real result, I got less than 50% of accuracy or even much lower, some numbers that read well, some that read 2 characters in a single image, some that didn't read.
When I remove the `-c tessedit_char_whitelist = 0123456789` configuration, I get the characters`4`, `\`, and the letter `g`.
How to make Pytesseract treat images as an only **single numerical character** instead of using a whitelist that still reads the text as **alphanumeric**?

PS: I know that OCR is can't 100% accurate. At least the accuracy can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751), tesseract 4.0 does not support whitelist characters with the LSTM model. You can fix this issue by upgrading Tesseract to the 4.1 version instead of using the legacy model (i.e., `--oem` flag).

Alternatively, you could try to use the flag `config='digits'` as proposed by [Robert Harris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8105296/robert-harris) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55030869/10250028) to force your pytesseract into returning only digits.

[This blog article](https://return2.net/python-tesseract-4-0-get-numbers-only/) proposes the creation of a python function that uses a simple regex to extract all numbers instead of juggling around with several flags and versions.

Comment: i think `config=digits` still doesn't treat images as only numeric. But only do the whitelisting in a different way