# OpenCV assertion failed in function 'setData'

Tags: python, opencv, knn

I read this **SOF** page [Simple Digit Recognition OCR in OpenCV-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python?rq=1)

Then I tried to run the below code by myself:

```
 import cv2
 import numpy as np


 samples = np.loadtxt('generalsamples.data',np.float32)
 responses = np.loadtxt('generalresponses.data',np.float32)
 responses = responses.reshape((responses.size,1))

 print "samples: \n",samples
 print "respnses: \n",responses

 model = cv2.ml.KNearest_create() 
 model.train(samples,cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE,responses)
```

Output:

```
samples:

[ 1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.   1.  65.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
  0.   0.   1.  65.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.  49.  16.   0.
  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.   1.  65.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.
  1.  65.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.  65.   0.   0.   0.   0.
  0.   0.   0.   1.  65.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.  65.   0.
  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   1.  11.  55.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
  1.   4.  62.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]

respnses:
[[ 7.]]
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    model.train(samples,cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE,responses)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) /home/shajal/opencv/opencv/modules/ml/src/data.cpp:259: error: (-215:Assertion failed) samples.type() == 5 || samples.type() == 4 in function 'setData'
```

What should I do?

I have reinstalled Opencv on my Ubuntu machine to resolve this.

Comment: Try providing a full qualified path to `np.loadtxt()` instead of relative path.

Comment: I tried that option .Give me the same error . @ZdaR

Comment: The I guess the shape of your sample matrix is wrong, what are the sources of these files ?

Answer (score 2):

When you use **model.train(samples,cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE,responses)** check next:

1. dimensions of *responses* must be (n,1), where n length of samples (n,m).
2. type of *samples* must be  *np.int64*

Comment: I am still getting error..?   Error: Assertion failed (samples.(322, 1)
type() == 5 || samples.type() == 4) in cv::ml::TrainDataImpl::setData, file C:\bld\opencv_1520732670222\work\opencv-3.4.1\modules\ml\src\data.cpp, line 259
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Prashant Kuma, please give me a link to data. In my opencv repo have no 'generalsamples.data' and 'generalresponses.data'  files.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error using OpenCV 3.4.0.12 and Python 3.6.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((layout == ROW_SAMPLE && responses.rows == nsamples) || (layout == COL_SAMPLE && responses.cols == nsamples)) in setData, file /io/opencv/modules/ml/src/data.cpp, line 298
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    model.train(samples,cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE,responses)
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/ml/src/data.cpp:298: error: (-215) (layout == ROW_SAMPLE && responses.rows == nsamples) || (layout == COL_SAMPLE && responses.cols == nsamples) in function setData
```

So I think you must have an error with the dimensions as 
`(layout == ROW_SAMPLE && responses.rows == nsamples) || (layout == COL_SAMPLE && responses.cols == nsamples)` says.

EDIT:

Yeah, the problem was the dimensions, after thinking a bit and understanding this, I finally realize what was happening, was easier to solve.

You do

```
responses = responses.reshape((responses.size,1))
```

Because responses is read as a float, not as an array. You get then `[[ 7. ]]` after doing the `reshape`. If you look at your samples array you'll see that it's a `[ numbers ]` array, not an `[[ numbers ]]` array.

Doing the same for samples makes everything work. **So add just after the samples creation: `samples = samples.reshape((1, samples.size))`**

Comment: I have edit with a possible solution which doesn't imply change the ROW_SAMPLE flag

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

After `samples = np.loadtxt('generalsamples.data',np.float32)`

Use `samples = np.array(samples).astype('float32')` to convert the numpy array type to `float32`