# How can I recognize hand-written numbers in customized image?

Tags: python, deep-learning, handwriting-recognition

The images have the following features (as attached[Numbers squeezed, with noisy drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wVBV.png)):

- The written numbers are squeezed in a square-shaped table on the image
- They don't share the same length
- Some numbers even have noisy drawing around them

What I need to do is to extract these numbers into readable format, like excel and upload to our ERP system. I googled but did not find suitable solution for this one

Comment: Give this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python) a read. Here the accepted answer makes use of custom image dataset for detecting numbers. You can do the same thing for your work, but use the [MNIST Digits dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/), since your image has handwritten data.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply, Argon. I am reading the article you mentioned now and see whether my problem can be solved.

Comment: @Argon Thanks Argon. It seems that I got a problem that  it is not easy to locate the table precisely (the image attached is only part of raw image). I tried to use match template in opencv but failed to locate it correctly. Any suggestion for me to going forward?