# How to import a Python/OpenCV/OCR script into Android Studio?

Tags: python, android-studio, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to build a small android app in which I will be able to recognize 7-segment digits or other type of numbers and display them on the screen.

I was able to make a small script in Python that can recognize any letters/numbers using OpenCV and Tesseract. For 7-segment digits, it doesn't seem to be as easy so I'm trying to use machine learning using this nice tutorial:
[Simple Digit Recognition OCR in OpenCV-Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python)

On the other side, I have to learn how to use Android Studio (3.4.2) but I managed to import the OpenCV library (3.4.0) using this protocol:
https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c

I have a general question. What strategy should I follow to conclude this project? Just the big lines ... or more if you want. Since I almost managed to make it work nicely using Python, how can I import my python code into Android Studio? Sorry for this stupid question. I just need to know if I'm taking the problem from the right angle. Is there an easy way to convert it to Java?....

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Please don't ask 3 totally different questions within one post, and please make sure your questions are [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Ok sorry, let's say my main question is how to import my python code into Android Studio so it can do the same job as when I run it using Pycharm and my webcam?